# Retrying a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, exception

I'm having an hard time figuring out how to implement a simple retry function in Python, where my code should have to try to send a message to telegram for a fixed amount of times, and if after tot times it will still fail, print an error. Instead, if it succeeds, break and go on.

So i have the following array:

```
Retries = [1, 2, 3]
```

Which means that, if it fails, wait one second, and if it fails again wait 2 seconds and then 3 seconds.

Then i have the following code:

```
for x in Retries:
    try:
        updater.bot.send_message(chat_id='myid', text='TEST')
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(x)
```

This code will try three times and wait 1, 2, 3, seconds between each try, but the problem is that:

1. Even if the message will be sent, it will still keep trying, while it needs to break
2. If it will fail for three times, it should print an error, i don't know how to do that

I found [this library](https://github.com/jd/tenacity), but i think it's overkill for such a simple task. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Your for loop will continues for all values in Retries, so if it sends on value one, it will still try on value 2 ect. You can end this with a break in the loop. After the 3 fails, you can simply add another condition to the loop

Comment: for 2, add an `else` block to your for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using pythons arcane but useful `else` clause for `for` loops:

```
for x in Retries:
    try:
        updater.bot.send_message(chat_id='myid', text='TEST')
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(x)
    else:
        break
else:
    # raise the real error here
```

If the function call succeeds, your code will `break` out of the loop and *not* trigger the `else` clause. The `else` clause is only triggered if the loop completes without a `break`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a break in the try block after sending the message like this -

```
for x in Retries:
    try:
        print('Hi there')
        break #Add a break here
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(x)
```

```
Hi there
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to print something when it will be done printing through the list and it will still fail?

Comment: @JayK23. There is, if you add an `else` to the loop

Comment: Yea there maybe another interesting way, i am trying to explore that. will edit my answer accordingly